# Android lollipop toolbar switch between open/close drawer and back button

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer, android-appcompat, android-toolbar

I had standart navigation drawer, but now i'm trying to modify it, using toolbar.

Earlier my code looked like:
**MainActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.v("MAIN", "CREATE");
    initViews();
    setListeners();

    getFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            shouldDisplayHomeUp();
        }
    });

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
}
```

**NavigationDrawerFragment.java**

```
public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
    mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), mDrawerLayout,
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getToolbar(),
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) {
                return;
            }

            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) {
                return;
            }

            if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to prevent auto-showing
                // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
            }
            if (mDrawerListView != null) {

            }
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
        }
    };

    // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce them to the drawer,
    // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
    if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.

    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);

    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}
```

Now i modified my code:
**MainActivity.java**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    if (mToolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    initViews();
    setListeners();

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));


    shouldDisplayHomeUp();

    getFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            mBackCount++;
            shouldDisplayHomeUp();
        }
    });
}
```

**NavigationDrawerFragment.java**

```
public void setUp(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
    mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
    mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), mDrawerLayout,
            ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getToolbar(),
            R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) {
                return;
            }

            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            if (!isAdded()) {
                return;
            }

            if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                // The user manually opened the drawer; store this flag to prevent auto-showing
                // the navigation drawer automatically in the future.
                mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager
                        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
                sp.edit().putBoolean(PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, true).apply();
            }
            if (mDrawerListView != null) {

            }
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu(); // calls onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
            super.onDrawerSlide(drawerView, slideOffset);
        }
    };

    // If the user hasn't 'learned' about the drawer, open it to introduce them to the drawer,
    // per the navigation drawer design guidelines.
    if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState) {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }

    // Defer code dependent on restoration of previous instance state.

    mDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);

    mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        }
    });

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}
```

And **shouldDisplayHomeUp** function:

```
public void shouldDisplayHomeUp (){
    boolean canBack = getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0;
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.getDrawerToggle().setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(!canBack);
}
```

But the back arrow is not shown

I tried call

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(canBack);
getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(canBack);
```

So the back arrow appers but clicking on it has no effect

Comment: You want to change the back arrow when you have more than one fragment on your backstack?

Comment: Yes, and provide back navigation instead opening drawer

Comment: with actionbar this works perfect

Comment: See my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/29292130/746347

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From the docs:

> To allow Up navigation with the app icon in the action bar, call
>   setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled():

```
@Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     ...
     getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); }
```

> This adds a left-facing caret alongside the app icon and enables it as an action
>   button such that when the user presses it, your activity receives a
>   call to onOptionsItemSelected(). The ID for the action is
>   android.R.id.home.

This means that you will have to implement your back routine on `onOptionsItemSelected` and check for `R.id.home`. To avoid calling the routine when you click on the hamburger menu check for `canback` too on `onOptionsItemSelected`.

http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html#up

**EDIT**

To archieve what you want you will have to implement your own navigation routine.

```
    mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(shouldBack()) {
               //call onbackpressed or something
                if(displayBackAgain)
                    return; //return after so you don't call syncState();       
            }else if (mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen())
                mNavigationDrawerFragment.closeDrawer();
            else
                mNavigationDrawerFragment.openDrawer();
            mNavigationDrawerFragment.getActionBarDrawerToggle().syncState();
        }
    });
}
```

To enable the backbutton icon just call `getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` to disable it just call `mNavigationDrawerFragment.getActionBarDrawerToggle().syncState();`

Comment: yes, but it doesn't work for toolbar from appcompat_v21

Comment: setNavigationOnClickListener doesn't catch click events

Comment: You have to set it after you call `setup()`

Comment: I'm having an issue with AppCompat v7. I can see the hamburger icon just fine but when I hide it and try to show the home (up affordance) it never shows. Thoughts?

Comment: @PedroOliveira Yup. That is always called in onPostCreate. I even tried calling it again but no luck. This only happened when using the Toolbar as the ActionBar. When I switched back to not using the Toolbar this problem no longer happens.

Answer (score 3):

I found a way to control the back button and the nav. It worked with me. 
First , set up:

```
private void setupNav () {

    this.toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(this.toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    this.mActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, this.mDrawerLayout, this.toolbar, 0, 0);

    this.mActionBarDrawerToggle.setToolbarNavigationClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //catch back button here.
        }
    });
    this.mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(this.mActionBarDrawerToggle);
    this.mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
}
```

Important thing, this is the way I hide the hamburger and show the back button. You have to put this code in the place you want to show back button. I also lock the Nav when showing back button.

```
if (!isShowBackButton) {
        mActionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
    } else {

        mActionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
        //enable back button
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Son, this worked for me and saved a lot of time.