# toolbar back button functionality

Tags: android, android-toolbar

I am having an issue with the toolbar and the back button. Here is the setup I have:

[image]

When I add a detail fragment, I animate the toolbar hamburger as outlined [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577006/animate-drawer-icon-into-arrow-on-setdisplayhomeasupenabled/26577437#26577437) and this causes the hamburger to animate to an arrow.

Even in the comments section, a user mentions:

> This works perfectly. Just set start=0 and end=1 to go from hamburger
>   to arrow, and start=1 and end=0 for arrow to hamburger. One thing
>   you'll have to keep track of is when the drawer is closed when the
>   arrow is shown. At this point, the hamburger ends up being shown
>   (because of the drawer's slide), which you'll have to correct.

But I cannot figure out how to get the back arrow to function properly. When I press the back arrow, the drawer opens and the detail fragment does not pop. How should I go about implementing this?

## Questions

- How should I animate hamburger to back arrow when adding a detail fragment? assuming the [linked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HCUpu.png) solution is not good enough.
- How do I override the back arrow to perform only specific functions I wish? like animate to hamburger, pop back stack and **NOT** open the drawer.

Comment: well-versed question, +1 for you bro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After several hours of searching and playing around, I was able to build a solution that delivered on each requirement. Sources: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26671412/android-lollipop-toolbar-switch-between-open-close-drawer-and-back-button?rq=1),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26577006/animate-drawer-icon-into-arrow-on-setdisplayhomeasupenabled?lq=1)

```
detailFragmentActive = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    ...
    mToolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(detailFragmentActive) {
                        onBackPressed();
                        //if(displayBackAgain)
                        //return; //return after so you don't call syncState();
                    }else if (mDrawerLayou.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START))
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                    else
                        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

                    mDrawerToggle.syncState();
                }
            });
}

private void animateHamburger(boolean isArrow){
        int start = 0, end = 1;

        if(isArrow){
            detailFragmentActive = false;
            start = 1; end = 0;
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
        }else{
            detailFragmentActive = true;
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
        }
        ValueAnimator anim = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(start, end);
        anim.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                float slideOffset = (Float) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                mDrawerToggle.onDrawerSlide(mDrawerLayout, slideOffset);
            }
        });
        anim.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator());
        anim.setDuration(500);
        anim.start();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    animateHamburger(true);
}

public void onFragmentChange(){
    ...
    animateHamburger(false);
}
```

Comment: This solved most of my issues perfectly. Still can't get the Hamburger icon to animate properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can set listener for this button:

```
toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (flagDeterminingAction) {
                drawerLayout.openDrawer(drawerListView);
            } else {
                onBackPressed();
               //or popbackstack or whatever you are using to going back in navigation
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, this was along the correct lines but some of the fine details were missing. I was able to find a solution eventually, please see my answer.